# How to hash a string to get a position in array

Tags: arrays, string, hash

I am doing this exercise in which i have to make a graph out of country names with adjacency list method.

anyways i have to store a node containing the country in the list depending on the name .

but i need a hash function that recieves the name of the country and gives me a reasonable number to store in array.

Comment: what language do you use? what hash algorithms you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

> [String.GetHashCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to hash a string. Generally, a hash function takes the size of the container and uses that to give you a number between 0 and (size-1). For example,

```
int hash( char* string, int size )
{
    int len = strlen( string );
    int hash = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i )
        hash += string[ i ];

    return hash % size;
}
```